# Is there a Quick Look plug-in for ZIP files?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

Is there a Quick Look plug-in that works with ZIP files, and that lists all the files contained in the archive? It is also fine if it lists at least some of the files.

Comment: Also, check out http://www.quicklookplugins.com/ for more great plugins.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, [Better Zip](http://macitbetter.com/BetterZip-Quick-Look-Generator)  does a fair job.

Comment: [homebrew](http://brew.sh) + [cask](https://caskroom.github.io/)  users can install the QuickLook plugin with `brew cask install betterzipql`.

Comment: It seems that the Quick Look plugin is now part of the Better Zip installation — `brew cask install betterzip`

Comment: It also seems that betterzip is commercial, so to use the QL viewer you need to purchase betterzip.

Comment: `brew install --cask betterzipql`

Answer (score 5):

There's also the open source [qlZipInfo](https://github.com/srirangav/qlZipInfo) that works for .zip, .jar, .tar, .tar.gz, .tar.bz2, .tar.Z, .xar, .pkg, .deb, .rpm, .7z, .xz, .cab, .gz, .lha, .hqx, .sit, .iso, .cdr, and .toast files.

Install instructions are given on its GitHub page; it supports macOS from 10.6 to the current release (13+). It provides a simple list of files and directories (if present) with totals.

If you run in problems with brew installation you can just download the dmg from the [releases](https://github.com/srirangav/qlZipInfo/releases) page and install it manually.

Comment: This worked for me. Added a cask for it `brew install iloveitaly/tap/qlzipinfo`

Comment: This command doesn't work anymore since the tap hasn't been updated, I'll switch to betterzip

Comment: As of 06.06.2023 it works on macOS Ventura 13.3.1 on Apple Silicon M1.

Comment: I have just installed this extension and reset quicklook, but it seems with no effects at all. qlZipInfo is not even listed among the Quick Look extensions in Settings.

Comment: qlZipInfo is working for me on Apple Silicon w/ Sonoma 14.2.1, but it seems to not detect every type of zip file, so it works on some but not on others.  For example, it works on JAR files and .tar.gz files that I've created myself, but it doesn't work on a zip file provided by a colleague.

Answer (score 1):

WinZip installs one but BetterZip's is better, although includes an advert for BetterZip each time you use it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is [The Archive Browser](https://theunarchiver.com/archive-browser).  It is a commercial tool as well but will show the contents of various file types.

From the site:

> The Archive Browser lets you easily peek into the archive, find the files you need, preview and extract them without unarchiving everything. Quick Look any file or folder and open them right from the archive